# simple php/jquery contact form-- adding a subject

Tags: php, jquery, forms, email

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.dzyngiri.com/index.php/slick-contact-form-using-jquery-php/) to create a simple PHP/jQuery contact form to grab user information and send to a specified email address. It works flawlessly, the only change I'd like to make is to specify a subject in the messages that go out (not on the part of the user-- I'm actually only going to have one field for the email address-- just what PHP sets as a default subject line)

The config.php is as follows:

```
<?php
// To
define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL", 'address@test.com');
?>
```

I'm wondering if I can simply add a line specifying a default subject for the emails as "Contact Form Data" or is this more involved?

Thanks for any guidance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you could define a subject the same way like:

```
define("MY_SUBJECT", 'Some Subject');
```

and then simply change

```
mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
        "From: ".$name." \r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

to

```
mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, MY_SUBJECT, $message,
        "From: ".$name." \r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

to use it in the mail.

Comment: these are all great answers, thanks! I also realized I could just define a variable like so: `$subject = 'Contact Form Data'` -- anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: using a variable is fine. constants make more sense when you're going to use them all over your project as their scope is global :) http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do this this by editing this section..

```
if(!$error)
{
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
    "From: ".$name." \r\n"
    ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}
}
```

Here, enter your subject instead of $subject..

```
if(!$error)
{
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, "Contact Form Data", $message,
    "From: ".$name." \r\n"
    ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for..

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`define("EMAIL_SUBJECT", 'Contact Form Data')`

```
mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $message,
        "From: ".$name." \r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```